# A growing currency versus USD

Tags: currency, usd-us-dollar

I checked the [graphs](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GBPUSD%3DX/chart?p=GBPUSD%3DX) of many currencies such as the Australian Dollar, Euro, Turkish Lira, Indian Rupee, Stirling Pound, etc. In recent years, all of the currencies that I am familiar with are  decreasing in value when exchanged to American dollars.

Some currencies look stable versus USD like Azerbaijani Manat but it is the government rate and in the actual market, their values decrease a lot more than many others.

My question is, are there any growing currencies versus USD in the past few years?  I am not an economist but it seems that there must be many currencies increasing their values when exchanged to USD in order for  the total global balance to be zero.

Comment: Swiss Franc (CHF) is the obvious exception: http://www.netdania.com/currencies/usdchf/netdania_fxa

Comment: Why must "the total global balance be zero"? Why can't there be one economy that grows relative to all others?

Comment: By “total global balance”, I assume you mean something like the sun of all trade surpluses and deficits globally. This would be zero because it’s a zero-sum game. But why would it predict that USD isn’t the strongest in any particular period?

Comment: Welcome to **personal finance** stackexchange. General questions about economics are [off-topic here](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but you can ask them on the [**Economics** stackexchange website](https://economics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It is not the case that some currencies must be getting stronger relative to USD if some are getting weaker.

If A is getting stronger relative to B and B is getting stronger relative to C then A must be getting stronger relative to C.